# How do I execute the $watch callback before ng-repeat filter kicks in?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a `ng-repeat` that loops through an array of resource objects with a filter, much like this.

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items | filter: { hidden: false}'>
  <div my-custom-directive ng-model='item'></div>
</div>
```

Then, in the directive, I'd like to monitor each resource object for change.

```
myApp.directive('myCustomDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      myDirectiveItem: '=ngModel'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="myCustomDirective.hidden = true">Hide</button>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$watch('myDirectiveItem', function(oldValue, newValue){
        console.log('I have changed'); // Never called
      }, true);
    }
  };
});
```

But the $watch callback is never called for a changing object. I assume that is because, in the cycle, the filter takes precedence, so that the watched resource object is not available in that scope anymore.

How can I force $watch callback to execute before the object is removed from the collection?

// Edit

I'd like to point out that if I remove `| filter: { hidden: false }` in my code everything works as expected and `I have changed` is displayed. It just doesn't work with the filter.

Comment: You should be watching myDirectiveItem not item.

Comment: As Gruff Bunny said you should be watching for myDirectiveItem as scope in your directive doesn't have an idea about 'item' from parent scope

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I corrected that in the example code. But this is not the actual problem.

Comment: If you want to watch for items added or removed from the collection it would make more sense to watch the collection on the scope of where items is defined rather than in the directive. The directive should represent an item rather than the collection.

Comment: What I really want is to call $update on the changed item of the collection. `item.hidden` is probably a bad example, it's just a property of the item.

Comment: There's still a reference to item in the ng-click. If you change that to myDirectiveItem the watch should fire.

Comment: Again, I'm sorry for the typo, this is not the actual code. The watch is firing perfectly (without using the filter in ng-repeat). The problem only occurs with the `filter` in the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
myApp.directive('myCustomDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      myDirectiveItem: '=ngModel'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click='item.hidden = true'>Hide</button>',
    link: function(scope) {

    // check that all items in ng-repeat loaded  
    if (scope.$last) {
        // watch scope.myDirectiveItem
        scope.$watch(scope.myDirectiveItem, function(oldValue, newValue){
          console.log('I have changed'); // Never called
        }, true);
      }          
    }
  };
});
```